# Save ViewModel when turning screen android

Tags: android

I am learning how to code in Android, and the book I was learning from said to save the screen state you should use

```
    val provider  = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
    val quizViewModel = provider.get(QuizViewModel::class.java)
    Log.d(TAG, "Got a QuizViewModel: $quizViewModel")
```

when I added this code, `ViewModelProviders.of` had a strikethrough, and I found out it was deprecated.

What is the current correct way to not have the screen reset when you rotate the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `val quizViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(QuizViewModel::class.java)`